# Why the Emission on Hair Particle System is disable?

Tags: hair, system, emission

I need to edit the NUMBER of EMISSION, but it disabled after I use WEIGHT PAINT with VERTEX GROUPS.

How can I edit emission after this?

[image]

Comment: You have to "Delete Edit".

Comment: Thank you for the answer FFeller, is the issue that I tried to avoid, but that's it. I thought that I'm doing something wrong, becouse every time that I deleted it, I needed to adjust the hair mesh with COMB again, it's been a headache

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to *Object Mode* and *Delete Edit*, only after that, can you re-edit simulation properties again.